# Executing a Find Script with a range of dates as the criteria

Tags: date, scripting, filemaker

Im trying to create a Find Script on two date selection fields (Drop Down calendars) that automatically run each time the field is updated/changed (I understand this part aka script triggers) and the report will show the results that contain dates listed between the range selected.

Please Keep in mind that I'm quite new to this so please correct me where you think I could improve is you find or see anything else that appears to be wrong. Anyways, here is the Layout for my report where the selection fields and results field are highlighted.

[image: My Layout]

Here is the script code I've created and I'm trying to use.

```
"Pre Construction::Bid Date" ≥ "Bid Date Search::Start Date" & "Pre Construction::Bid Date" ≤ "Bid Date Search::Start Date"
```

Here is the error I get when I try to add/save this in/under the perform find -> specify dialog box.

[image]

Ive tried and set all the fields to use the exact same date layout and format (the xx/xx/xxxx) and ive still had no luck in created this type of search. Im hoping someone will be able to help me fix this or offer other solutions as to how I could go about creating this. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your attempt:

- First, you cannot use references to fields in a find request.
- Next, to find records within a specified range, you must use the *range operator* (two or three periods).

Now, you *could* populate variables with the range boundaries and use these in the find request instead of the fields, but it is much more convenient to skip stored find requests altogether and do simply:

```
Enter Find Mode [  ] 
Set Field [ Pre Construction::Bid Date; Bid Date Search::Start Date  & ".." & Bid Date Search::End Date ] 
Perform Find [  ]
```

Of course, we are assuming that the `Start Date` and `End Date` fields are **global** fields.

Comment: Haha awesome! You da man! Im just started to learn this program in my free time to see if i can help my dad cut costs for his company and this program is pretty cool. Thanks mate!

Comment: @WChampion I recommend joining one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform - these are much more suitable for helping beginners.

Comment: One last hopefully quick question, When the script is performed, I receive results as intended but there is no particular order to them, the dates appears in the order they were added and jump back around, is there a way to auto sort them as this script is performed? I know how to create another button to do it but if i could make it happen at the same time the user friendly-ness would be better

Comment: Wait nevermind, pretty sure i can just add another line to the scirpt code after the perform find

Comment: Just add a `Sort Records` step after `Perform Find`.